# Python if statement doesn't call function?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I have following code:

```
 def timee():
    time.sleep(5)
    f = open("input.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    intimetxt = lines[0]
    now = datetime.now()
    currenttime = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    if currenttime == intimetxt:
        start()
    if not currenttime == lines[0]:
        timee() 
 timee()
```

It should read a sertain time from a .txt file and if the time is the current time it should call another function. My problem is that even if the time is the same, it won't call the function.

Hope somebody can help me out:)

Comment: This is very unreliable. Use something like [cron](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) instead

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the contents of the text file?

Comment: You could change your two if statements to one if/else. Besides, it really depends on the content of your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you read from file using readlines() includes newline, try doing

```
intimetxt = lines[0].strip()
```

also, the condition may be simplified to:

```
if currenttime == intimetxt:
    start()
else:
    timee()
```

Even with that, the code still has problems, its recursively calling itself and opens the input file for every call. Try using while loop or calculating time to the start event and issuing right sleep()